# Import excel file without changing into csv format using php

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpmyadmin

I want to import excel data into phpmyadmin without changing it into csv format. Is there any php code for doing this.Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are some PHP libraries with which you can read your Excel files and insert to MySQL:

- [`Php-Excel`](https://code.google.com/p/php-excel/)
- [`PhpExcel`](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)
- [`Php-Excel-Reader`](https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/)

Documentation is available for all of them.